# Jenkins - pass build name to code being built

Tags: jenkins, build

I have my Jenkins job defined to use a timestamp for the build name.  I'd also like to be able to use that build name in the code being built.   For example, suppose my application prints a "startup" message during initialization.   Ideally, I would be able to somehow inject the build name into this startup message.
Example:
    Application XYZ, build 20160503-0420, is starting up...

I'm curious what sort of techniques folks have come up with to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first insert build number directly into your code it`s very bad practice.

We create debian package by Jenkins. Debian packages contains control file, some kind of description of package, version, dependency, etc.

In our repo control file contains

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Package: #packagename
Version: 0.1.0+#build~#repo
```

As you see we keep fixed only major version of software
Then we create package we replace texts started by # with build variables

```
sed -i 's/#build/$(BUILD_NUMBER)/' $(FAKEROOT)/DEBIAN/control
sed -i 's/#repo/$(REPONAME)/' $(FAKEROOT)/DEBIAN/control
sed -i 's/#packagename/$(PROJECTNAME)/' $(FAKEROOT)/DEBIAN/control
```

And after that we publish, deploy, send email, doing all Jenkins magic.
I think you can build binary and distribute it

Of course if you want to add this changes into you repository you can use [Git publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), or another source management systems, but tell you again this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

We use powershell plugin in Jenkins and this is how we write our job ...

Write-Host Build id $env:BUILD_NUMBER started at Get-Date

For more build parameters refer to below URL

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables